# RShiny - When printing the table from renderDT it prints the HTML code for the title instead of just the title

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

In my shiny app I want to be able to create an excel or pdf from a table. I am using renderDT to create the table, and buttons inside options in that function to have that feature. ON the shiny app once it is ran, when clicking on the pdf button the table prints well, but the title on top of it shows the HTML code for the title, instead of the title itself. There are other ways to create the title but I am doing it in a specific way so I can add a logo to the title.

Here is some sample code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(tableHTML)


# Data
Op_dataGen  <- data.table(Var1 = 1:100,
                          Var2 = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE))
 

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$style(".main-sidebar {padding-top: 74px}"),
  
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML('
         .skin-blue .main-header .logo {background-color:#1F3758;   font-size:auto; display:contents; 
         font-weight:bold; }

         .skin-blue .main-header .logo b {color:#fff; font-size:auto; font-weight:bold;}
    '
    ))),
  
  dashboardPage(
    
    
    # a) header 
     dashboardHeader(

     title = span(img(src="logo.png", width = 250), tags$b('Organization Title')),
     tags$li(tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 74px}"),
             tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 74px, width: 90px}"),
             class = "dropdown")


    ),
    
    dashboardSidebar(width=250, 

                     
                     sidebarMenu(id = 'sidebar',
                                 
                                 #Tabs#
                                 menuItem('View Table', tabName = 'table'))
    ),

    # c) body 
    dashboardBody(
     
      
      fluidRow(
        
        tabItems(
          
          tabItem(tabName = 'table',
                  box(width = 12,
                      title = 'Total NumberTable',
                      DTOutput('TableG'))
          ))))
    )
  )
    

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  TableG <- copy(Op_dataGen)
  
  output$TableG <- renderDT({
    
    TableG
    
  },
  
  
  rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = 'Buttons',
  options = list(
    pageLength = 100,
    scrollY = '360px',
    scrollX = TRUE, 
    dom = 'Bfrtip', 
    buttons = c('copy', 'excel', 'pdf')
    )
  )
  })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the title you want like this:

```
output$TableG <- renderDT({
  datatable(
    TableG, 
    rownames = FALSE,
    extensions = "Buttons",
    options = list(
      pageLength = 100,
      scrollY = '360px',
      scrollX = TRUE, 
      dom = 'Bfrtip', 
      buttons = list(
        list(extend = "copy", title = "TheTitleYouWant"),
        list(extend = "excel", title = "TheTitleYouWant"),
        list(extend = "pdf", title = "TheTitleYouWant")
      )
    )
  )
})
```